# Android GPL app that opens a closed source app

Tags: gpl, proprietary-code, google-play, android

Is legal if I edit an open source app with GPL license and make it open source again with GPL license but for doing some tasks it opens another app that is not open source?

For example: GPL app sends a word to a dictionary app to show meaning and then returns to GPL app, and if it doesn't exist, opens Google Play to buy that app.

And if the user didn't buy that app he/she can not see the meaning of that word because he / she didn't buy the dictionary app so it can't send data to dictionary to show the meaning of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, non-free software and GPL software can be "combined" if the combination forms an aggregate instead of being a single software deriving from the two.

This is mentioned in section 5 of GPL v3:

> A compilation of a covered work with other separate and independent works, which are not by their nature extensions of the covered work, and which are not combined with it such as to form a larger program, in or on a volume of a storage or distribution medium, is called an “aggregate” if the compilation and its resulting copyright are not used to limit the access or legal rights of the compilation's users beyond what the individual works permit. Inclusion of a covered work in an aggregate does not cause this License to apply to the other parts of the aggregate.

The model that you describe seems to fit in this description and thus would be legal indeed.